# Laravel Livewire uploading files to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, laravel-livewire

I am attempting to upoad files using laravel livewire.

I have created my S3 bucket. I have also created my user with AWSS3FullAccessRights.

By default my s3 bucket has public access turned off.

When I upload a files I am getting a 403 forbidden error. The request URL is:

```
https://[bucket_name].s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/livewire-tmp/HeFkgK7BTeFv2voaPzMPJdwqX69KQ4-metac2FtcGxlLW1wNC1maWxlLm1wNA%3D%3D-.mp4?x-amz-acl=private&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAS3BSKYVMYVLYCB44%2F20201025%2Fap-southeast-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201025T041359Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=9e87a654cbeab84772c18a950741027e7eeea1ad41b28e7b1c84a60cf2266147.
```

The file is not getting uploaded to S3 at all. My livewire settings file is set to s3. I have entered my key, secret, region and bucket name into my .env file.

Are there any other permissions I need to setup on AWS for this to work.  All the tutorials I have looked at don't work and not sure why.

Any heklp would be appreciated

Thanks
Danny

Comment: This is S3 pre-signed url. What  role/user generated this url? The pre-sign url permissions are tided to who/what ever generated it, not your own permissions.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the user that I created and assign S3FullAccess rights. I have only one user in IAM

Comment: did you solve this? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was with allowing cross-origin requests. I had to insert the following code into the CORS configurations in the S3 bucket

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example1.com</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example2.com</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: thanks, digital ocean spaces CORS Setting "Header *" saved my time